# 2 CSS (при разных размерах окна браузера)

Tags: javascript, css

Реализовал 2 CSS
JS проверяет и выдаёт тот, который подходит.
Всё работает. Но получается в статике.
Хотелось бы реализовать динамический подхват CSS, без нажатия F5.
Без лишних framework'ов.
Пробовал вешать выбор на `window.onresize = function()`, но как-то не срабартывает.
Как такую задумку реализовать, без громоздких framework'ов?

Comment: если нужно просто изменение в зависимости от ширины viewport'а, то это делается через media queries

Answer (score 1):

Ну например так:

html:

```
<link id="style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
var style = document.getElementById('style');
window.onresize = function() {
window.innerWidth < 1000 ? style.setAttribute('href','style2.css') : style.setAttribute('href','style1.css');
}
</script>
```

css(style1.css)

```
body {background:red;}
```

css(style2.css)

```
body {background:green;}
```

Когда ширина браузера < 1000px показываем style2, иначе style1.

Но зачем, когда есть [media queries](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media).

Можно еще например тегу body менять класс, а в стилях делать привязку к нему

```
.style1 .mystyle {background:red;}
.style2 .mystyle {background: green;}
```

Comment: Скрипт проверил - не работает.
А вот про "media queries" знал, но как-то по побаивался за совместимость (наверное зря).

Comment: Так и у меня скрипт ловил ширину и работал.
`if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 1024)
 {
  document.write('<link href="settings/style_mini.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">');
 }
 else
 {
  document.write('<link href="settings/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">');
 }`
Сделал 1-файл, но с media queries.
Всё работает прекрасно!

Comment: @I_CaR они работают во всех браузерах еще с < 2010 года

Answer (score 0):

надо подключать через media разные файлы, например:

```
link rel='stylesheet' media='(min-width: 1600px)' href='URL_большой.css'
link rel='stylesheet' media='(max-width: 1599px) and (min-width: 800px)' href='URL_средний.css'
```